# Why do pyautogui.hotkey function sometimes work and sometimes not?

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyperclip

when I'm using this code, the function pyautogui.click works just once in a while and that's mean my ctrl v doesn't work, someone know why?

```
pyautogui.click(1480, 861)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pyautogui.click(1970, 567)
        time.sleep(0.7)
        pyautogui.click(1977, 1354)
        time.sleep(1)
        
        pyperclip.copy("Hey thats do ctrl v")
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(0.7)
        pyautogui.click(1952, 343)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

Tried to change the function "hotkey()" for another function but it didn't work, so I tried to add pyperclip.copy
and it seems that's its still doesn't work